# Parse Spark JSON format RDD value into different values

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to do some kind of flatMap in Spark (Scala) to a RDD that has N values and one is in JSON format.

For example, when I print the RDD I have something similar to this:

```
myRDD.collect().foreach(println)

[2020,{'COL_A': 1064.3667, 'col_B': 14534.2}]
[2020,{'COL_A': 1064.3667, 'col_B': 145.2}]
[2020,{'COL_A': 1064.3667, 'col_B': 15576.2}]
```

And I would like to have something like this:

```
[2020,1064.3667,14534.2]
[2020,1064.3667,145.2]
[2020,1064.3667,15576.2]
```

I don't know if this can be done with flatmap...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using built in `json4s` library to parse json.

**Import required libraries**

```
scala> import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._

scala> import org.json4s._
import org.json4s._
```

```
scala> val rdd = spark
.sparkContext
.parallelize(
    Seq(
        (2020,"""{"COL_A": 1064.3667, "col_B": 14534.2}"""),
        (2020,"""{"COL_A": 1064.3667, "col_B": 145.2}"""),
        (2020,"""{"COL_A": 1064.3667, "col_B": 15576.2}""")
       )
)
```

```
scala> rdd.collect.foreach(println)
(2020,{"COL_A": 1064.3667, "col_B": 14534.2})
(2020,{"COL_A": 1064.3667, "col_B": 145.2})
(2020,{"COL_A": 1064.3667, "col_B": 15576.2})
```

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

val transformedRdd = rdd.map { c =>
      implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
      val values = parse(c._2).extract[Map[String,Double]].values.toList
      (c._1,values.head,values.last)
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.
```

```
scala> transformedRdd.collect.foreach(println)
(2020,1064.3667,14534.2)
(2020,1064.3667,145.2)
(2020,1064.3667,15576.2)
```